# Crear un DataFrame a partir de los datos de dos DataFrames diferentes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el **DataFrame base** con los siguientes **datos**:

[image: DataFrame 1 con los datos base]

Ahora tengo el segundo **DataFrame**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que espero es un tercer **DataFrame** con el producto de los valores del **DataFrame 1** con el factor del segundo **DataFrame** pero correspondientes para cáda máquina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a pivotar el segundo **DataFrame**, y a realizar una especie de BUSCARV de Excel en Python

`resultado = df2.merge(df1, on='Clave', how='left')[['Clave', 'Valor2', 'Valor1']]`

pero no logro obtener el resultado esperado.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

normalmente seria esto según yo:

Supongamos que tienes estos dos DataFrames donde A & B es el nombre de Columna y entre [] los valores que estan en la fila de la esa columna

```
data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
data2 = {'A': [7, 8, 9], 'B': [10, 11, 12]}
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Multiplicar los valores

```
result_df = df1 * df2
```

Concatenar los DataFrames

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, result_df], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df1*df2'], axis=1)
```

Mostrar el DataFrame resultante

```
print("DataFrame resultante:")
print(concatenated_df)
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Brayam por tu respuesta, pero no es eso lo que estoy buscando, fíjate que los datos del segundo dataframe están en fila las máquinas y luego quiero tenerlas cómo columnas..